# Working with dictionary python

Tags: python

When i run my program (anagram solver) i get error Unhashable type: list. What should i setWord to? I cant do set([word]) as that gives the same error also.

The word.txt contains a bunch of words on a newline.

here is code:

```
def main():
    wordList = readMatrix()
    print(lengthWord())

def readMatrix():
    wordList = []
    strFile = open("words.txt", "r")
    lines = strFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        word = sorted(line.rstrip().lower())
        wordList.append(word)
    return tuple(wordList)

def lengthWord():
    lenWord = 7
    sortDict = {}
    wordList = readMatrix()
    for word in wordList:
        if len(word) == lenWord:
            sortWord = ''.join(sorted(word))
            setWord = set([word])
            if sortWord not in sortDict:
                sortDict[sortWord] = set()
            sortDict[sortWord].add(setWord)
    return sortDict


main()
```

Comment: Use `frozenset([word])`.

Comment: cant use frozenset since its for class and we havent learned frozenset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to map sorted words to sets of their originals:

```
sortDict = {
  'dgo': set('dog', 'god'),
  ...
}
```

So no need for `setWord`; just do:

```
sortDict[sortWord].add(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) instead of a list:

```
setWord = word,  # or setWord = tuple(word)
```

Another possibility is to use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) if you want a set inside a set:

```
setWord = frozenset([word])
```

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) explains:

> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable [...]

And as can be seen in [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) and [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) documentations - they are immutable types.

Comment: `setWord` is a string... he has problem in this line: `sortDict[sortWord].add(setWord)`

Comment: @solofisher Sorry, I can't guess what you did exactly, and what's the error. If you get "unhashable type list" error, then it doesn't lie - you definitely are trying, somewhere in your code, to add a list to a dict/set, not a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You want to map from a normalized form (the sorted word) to a list of actual tokens.